# Adding material UI to Asp net core react application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I have complete asp net core react web application but I need a component from the React MUI library...

I tried installing the MUI package using:

npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

And then coded this simple test page:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

    export default function Test() {
        return (
            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                <Button variant="text">Text</Button>
                <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
            </Stack>
        );
    }
```

while this is my app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/base/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/base/Home';

import Test from './components/testing/Test';

import './custom.css'

export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/test' component={Test} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

The test.js is a functional component while the other older pages are classes as I'm slowly switching to functional components.

Everything works fine except when I try to go into test.js, nothing loads up in the browser and the console gives me this error:

[console errors picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDwtR.png)

I really cannot understand why this happens, It does the same thing if I try to use react-bootstrap, while it works with the pre installed reactstrap...

Lastly if anyone can help, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.0",
    "linq": "^4.0.0",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^7.5.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.20"
  }
}
```

Thanks...

EDIT: even https://github.com/cahilfoley/react-snowfall doesn't work, what might be the problem...

This is my "npm ls react-native":

```
+-- react-snowfall@1.1.2

| `-- react-dom@17.0.2

`-- react-switch@7.0.0

  `-- react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
```